# Do there exist $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that $ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f > 0 \quad\forall 0<x\le 1, 0< y\le 1$ and...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Do there exist $a,b,c,d,e,f$ satisfying:
\begin{cases}
ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f > 0 \quad\forall 0<x\le 1, 0< y\le 1\\ 
a+b+c+d+e+f \le 1\\
a+d+f \le 0\\ 
b+e+f \le 0\\ 
f\le 0
\end{cases}?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. 
$$(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(p,q,r,-p,-q,0)\ \ \text{where $\ p\le 0,q\le 0,0\lt r\le 1$}$$ works because
$$\begin{align}ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f&=px^2+qy^2+rxy-px-qy\\&=p(x^2-x)+q(y^2-y)+rxy\\&\ge 0+0+rxy\\&\gt 0\end{align}$$
for $\forall 0\lt x\le 1, 0\lt y\le 1$.

Comment: Sorry there's a typo, it should be $a+b+c+d+e+f \le 1$.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been aware of your modifications because I didn't receive any notifications (you should have mentioned me or something). I'll check your answer in a few hours and get back. Thanks!